# Query for a field in an object in array with Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use Mongo to query for entries that have a particular value in a field in an object in an array.

For example, let's say I want to find all objects where field1 has an array of objects, one of which has the field 'one' with a value of 1. This query should return the following object from my collection:

```
{_id: 0000, field1: [{one: 1, two: 2}, {one: 'uno', two: 'dos'}]}
```

Comment: Do you mean an array of documents?

Comment: Well it's an array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I suppose what you need is:

```
db.collection.find( { field1: { $elemMatch: { one: 1 } } } );
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

Comment: How about in a deep nested array

Comment: what's the syntax for saving the result of this query in a javascript list?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but a simpler way to perform this query is to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents):

```
db.collection.find({'field1.one': 1})
```