# MongoDB C driver how to find object field value in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

i try to find way in C Driver to somthing that is similar to : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

as answerd in this thread :
[Query for a field in an object in array with Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075205/query-for-a-field-in-an-object-in-array-with-mongo)

i have this json and i want check if  the value of sessions.id == 1234556:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5768e43"),
    "APPID": {
        "Number": 0,

    },
    sessions: [
        {
            id:1234556,
            "setOID": {
                "Number": 0 

            },
            "custID": {
                "Number": 0 

            },

        },
        {
            id:133333,
            "setOID": {
                "Number": 2 

            },
            "custID": {
                "Number": 2 

            },

        },
     ]
}
```

how can it be done in the new C Driver ?

Comment: how you did that in he old one?

Comment: i did not im new to mongodb + c driver