# Omit certain field in an array mongo query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Similar to [Query for a field in an object in array with Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075205/query-for-a-field-in-an-object-in-array-with-mongo) The asker want to query a specific field in an object, but what I want is opposite to him.

My data

```
{   "_id": "ffb76dea811a6773c9481fd35262fe7f", 
    "fieldA" : "A", 
    "fieldB" : "B", 
    "fieldC" : [ 
        { "group1" : "100", "group2" : "200", "id" : "b0a05edd3cb0d35674174f34da1b3021"}, 
        { "group1" : "110", "group2" : "230", "id" : "b9071b34c21f948e69cb39df7dbf10a7"} 
    ]
}
```

How to query to get

```
{
    "fieldA" : "A", 
    "fieldC" : [ 
        { "group1" : "100", "group2" : "200" }, 
        { "group1" : "110", "group2" : "230" } 
    ]
}
```

**Key point is that I don't want `id` appear in my query result**

```
db.test.insertOne({"_id":"ffb76dea811a6773c9481fd35262fe7f","fieldA":"A","fieldB":"B","fieldC":[{"group1":"100","group2":"200","id":"b0a05edd3cb0d35674174f34da1b3021"},{"group1":"110","group2":"230","id":"b9071b34c21f948e69cb39df7dbf10a7"}]})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of a `find` in mongoDB is a `projection` option which is used to include or exclude fields from the result. In your case, you need to use it as follows:

```
db.test.find({},{"fieldC.id":0, fieldB: 0, "_id":0})
```

See here for how projection works https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/