# Find array in array data in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want find in this document groups:

```
      "document": {
        "groups": [
          {
            "id": "5ccd5f7f34f82b0e3315b2f6"
          },
          {
            "id": "73b43unbfkfmdmddfdf84jjk"
          }
         ]
      }
```

are contains some of my query array groups ID:

```
[ '5ccd5f7f34f82b0e3315b2f6',
 '5cdeded7ace07216f5873b5d',
 '5cdee5d114edac2cc00bb333' ]
```

Comment: Could you please share your document/schema and your desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for a field in an object in array with Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075205/query-for-a-field-in-an-object-in-array-with-mongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple find query suffices:

```
db.collection.find({ 'groups.id' : {$in : [ '5ccd5f7f34f82b0e3315b2f6',
                                            '5cdeded7ace07216f5873b5d',
                                            '5cdee5d114edac2cc00bb333' ] }})
```